# how to share login data among controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a `MainController` and a `ChatController`. The users login with `username`, `passwod` and `jobname`, which are controllered by `MainController`, but in `ChatController`, I still need parameter `jobname`, wondering how to pass it to `ChatController`?

I wrote methods 'saveJobname' and 'getJobname' in service `Auth`, but `getJobname` works well but `saveJobname` doesn't which could be seen via the `console.log(..)` statement in `ChatController`.

Here are some relevant codes:

```
 // ---------------------MainController--------------------
app.controller('MainController', ['Auth', '$scope', '$window', '$rootScope', function(Auth, $scope, $rootScope, $window) {

  $scope.info = Auth.info;
  var vm = this;
  vm.loginData = {};

  vm.doLogin = function() {
    // ...login processing

    Auth
      .login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
      .success(function(data) {

        // ...some more code here

        if (data.success) { // if login successfully, then save jobname
          $scope.info.myjobname = vm.loginData.jobname;
          //Auth.saveJobname(vm.loginData.jobname); //does NOT work either

          // ...some more codes here

          $window.location.href = $window.location.href + '/../job.html';
        }
      });
  };
}]);



// --------------------ChatController----------------------
app.controller('ChatController', ['Auth', ChatController]);

function ChatController(Auth) {
  // ...come other codes here;
  console.log(Auth.info.myjobname); // it prints 'hello.world!' but not 'vm.loginData.jobname';
  // ...come other codes here;
}



// ------------------- AuthService ------------------------
app.factory('Auth', function($http, $q) {
  var authFactory = {};
  authFactory.info = {
    myjobname: 'hello.world!'
  };

  // get the API from auth.post('/login', function(...){...})
  authFactory.login = function(username, password) {

    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', {

      username: username,
      password: password

    }).success(function(data) {
      //some code here about token processing
      return data;
    });
  };

  authFactory.saveJobname = function(jobname) {
    authFactory.info.myjobname = jobname;
  };

  authFactory.getJobname = function() {
    return authFactory.info.myjobname;
  };

  return authFactory;
});
```

I prefer the solution not using `$rootScope`, pls advise.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one variable inside `Auth` factory something like `authFactory.info = {}` in that you can define your `username`, `password` & `myjobname`.

While using them you need to just bind info object inside controller like

```
$scope.info = Auth.info
```

And `Auth` factory would be like this

```
// AuthService
app.factory('Auth', function($http, $q) {

  var authFactory = {};
  authFactory.info = {
    myjobname: 'hello.world!'
  };
  // get the API from auth.post('/login', function(...){...})
  authFactory.login = function(username, password) {

    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', {

      username: username,
      password: password

    }).success(function(data) {
      //some code here about token processing
      return data;
    });
  };

  authFactory.saveJobname = function(jobname) {
    authFactory.info.myjobname = jobname;
  };

  authFactory.getJobname = function(){
    return authFactory.info.myjobname;
  };

  return authFactory;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have also updated the code, but the problem is not solved, initial message "hello.world" could be printed, but login data `vm.loginData.jobname` can not be saved in authFactory.info and then pass to ChatController. @evc @Pankaj Parkar

Comment: As I suggested you should use `$scope.info = Auth.info` in your controller and then use `{{info.jobname}}` on your page will work

Comment: Sorry, I am some confused, maybe my question is not that clear, so simplily speaking, how can I let the statement `console.log(Auth.info.myjobname)`  in ChatController prints "SoftwareDeveloper" instead of "helloworld" if I login with jobname "SoftwareDeveloper"? I have updated my above code following your suggestions. Thank you @Pankaj Parkar